# How can I add quotation marks to NSString?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

How can I add quotation marks to NSString ?
for example, string = @"my string with "Big string"  ";

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put a backslash \ before the quotation mark. 
Example:

```
NSString *str = @"my string with \"Big string\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string = @"my string with \"Big string\" ";
```